# Sometime getting file not found error for http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/jquery.js and ESRI map doesn't load

Tags: esri

I'm using "js.arcgis.com/3.7" to implement esri maps. Sometime when i try to load page, I get below error and map doesn't load.

Error:

1. http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/jquery.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2. scriptError(…)(anonymous function) @ init.js:40 (console.error(a))

Below is my code:

```
  require([
               "esri/map",
               "esri/toolbars/draw",
               "dojo/parser",
               "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
               "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
               "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
               "dijit/form/Button",
               "dijit/WidgetSet",
               "dojo/domReady!"
                    ], function (
                Map,
                Draw,
                parser,
                LocateButton
              ) {
                parser.parse();
                var opts = {
                    basemap: "topo",
                    center: [-103.08, 44.05],
                    zoom: 17
                };
                map = new Map("mapDiv", opts);

                geoLocate = new LocateButton({
                    map: map
                }, "LocateButton");
                geoLocate.startup();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you're using the 3.7 JS API, but are getting an error referencing the 3.9 API?

Moreover, is there a reason you're not using the newest (3.18) API?

I'd have to see a full stack trace, but it's difficult to see why Esri would be referencing a module from a newer version of its API. They've provided a resource for their 3.18 API on using jQuery with Dojo, if you decide to switch to the newest version:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/framework_jquery.html

That said, I don't see any references to jQuery in your code, so without more information I'd imagine the issue is a broken internal reference in their 3.7 API.